# How to update the xml tag values using python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, parse-tree, xml.etree

I am new to Python, I like to know how to achive the following using python.

I have an XML file, I want to open the file and have to set new values for the tag .

If there any failure during update then the file goes original state

FileName: ABC.xml

```
<Root>
<Location>
<city>WrongCity</city>
<state>WrongState</state>
<country>WrongCountry</country>
</Location>
</Root>
```

Passing the filepath to some function.

```
def correctValues(filepath)
    # update the wrong information 
    try:
        set city = MYcity
        set state = somevalue
        set country = somedata
    except:
        Rollback to original file
```

The original file need to updated the with the corrected values if no issues during values update.

expected output:

```
<Root>
<Location>
<city>MYcity</city>
<state>somevalue</state>
<country>somedata</country>
</Location>
</Root>
```

If case any problems, the file should rollback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of problems are you expecting?

Comment: Issues while update the tag information. or while save the file or so..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to:

1. call a library to parse the XML into an actual tree of nodes;
2. modify that tree however you need to; and
3. write the new tree back out.

Using "bs4" (which has some problems, but often suffices), it would look something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import codecs

badCityDict = {  # List of corrections
    "Washingtun": "Washington",
    "Bolton": "Boston"
}

# Second parameter to constructor picks what parser bs4 should use.
tree = bs4(codecs.open(myfile, mode='r', encoding='utf-8'), 'lxml')

changeCount = 0
cityNodes = tree.find_all('city')
for cn in cityNodes:
    cnText = cn.string.strip()
    if cnText in badCityDict:
        cn.string.replace_with(badCityDict[cnText])
        changeCount += 1

### same thing for state, country, and so on...

if (changeCount > 0):
    print tree.prettify()
```